# set input variables in resource terraform

Tags: terraform

I am using the following resource

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "example" {
  for_each                  = toset(var.myenvironments_map[var.environment])

...

  db_instance_identifier_key = each.key

  dimensions = {
   DBInstanceIdentifier = db_instance_identifier
  }
}
```

and wanted to do something like the following

```
locals {
  `db_instance_identifier` = var.db_instance_identifier_key == "myKey" ? 
  "${avariable}" : "${aMap[var.db_instance_identifier_key].identifier}"
}

variable "db_instance_identifier_key" {
type = string
}
```

but when I run `terraform plan` I get: "The root module input variable "db_instance_identifier_key" is not set, and
│ has no default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to
│ provide a value for this variable."

Basically I want to compute `db_instance_identifier` based on `each.key` from the for_each.

Answer (score 0):

This is a local variable declaration:

```
locals {
  `db_instance_identifier` = var.db_instance_identifier_key == "myKey" ? 
  "${avariable}" : "${aMap[var.db_instance_identifier_key].identifier}"
}
```

This is a module input variable declaration:

```
variable "db_instance_identifier_key" {
type = string
}
```

You need to use one or the other, not both.

Comment: I have defined the `db_instance_identifier_key` because I need a way to staore the value of `eah.key` in order to compute the local `db_instance_identifier`. Is there another way to compute that value using `each.key`?

Comment: Storing the value of `each.key` and using it later inside a single resource like you are doing isn't even valid Terraform syntax. You can't declare variables and use them like that in Terraform. Terraform isn't a procedural language, it is declarative. Declaring the variable like you have does not allow you to "store the value of each.key" in any way. You have declared a module input variable.

Comment: You would need to do something like this in your cloudwatch metric resource: `DBInstanceIdentifier = each.key == "myKey" ?  avariable : aMap[each.key].identifier`